# Double Integral Over A Cylinder Not Centered On The Origin

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Given the formula: $$x^2+y^2+z^2=a^2$$

Which is bounded by: $$x^2+y^2=ax$$ and $$z = 0$$

I need to find the surface area but I'm having trouble figuring out the domain. I'm using :$z=\sqrt{a^2-x^2-y^2}$ since that acounts for the bound of $z=0$. I know I need to use the forumula: $S(A)=\int\int\sqrt{F_x^2+F_y^2+1}\,\mathrm{d}A$. So, I've found $F_x=-x(a^2-x^2-y^2)^{1/2}$ and $F_y=-y(a^2-x^2-y^2)^{1/2}$. How do I figure out the domain? The $x$ times the constant $a$ is throwing me off in $x^2+y^2=ax$.

My Incorrect Solution in Polar Coordinates:$$S(A)=\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\int_0^{a\cos(\theta)}\sqrt{x^2(a^2-x^2-y^2)+y^2(a^2-x^2-y^2)+1}\,r\mathrm{d}r\mathrm{d}\theta$$

I converted $x^2+y^2=ax$ into polar co-ordinates and I solved for $r$ to get $r=acos(\theta)$ but for some reason this is not the proper limit of integration, I'm stumped about what the proper limit of integration for $r$ should be.

Comment: $x^2+y^2+z^2=a^2$ is a sphere of radius $a$ with center at the origin. $x^2+y^2=ax$ is clearly a cylinder whose axis is the z-axis and has a circular cross-section (center at (a,2) and radius a/2). Can you sketch the region now?

Comment: Well I understand that $\theta$ would go from $-\pi/2$ to $\pi/2$ but how do I figure out the value for r since it's variable?

Comment: I just thought about converting the bounding equation to polar co-ordinates and then solving for r, is my attempted solution above correct?